# Exclude output of entries/users/products if category relation has particular field value

Tags: categories, relations

So basically what i have is a big set of categories (about 86 total, multi-level). Within my category fields i have a lightswitch with the handle 'private'. I would like to know how i would write a set/query to exclude any products/entries/users from appearing in a for loop if that item is in a category where the field 'private' is set to '1' meaning 'yes'.

Meaning if Product 'T-Shirt' is in category 'Awesome' and category 'Tubular' and category 'Ugly'. Assuming the category 'Ugly' has that field set to '1/yes'. When i run a for-loop for all products inside 'Awesome', how do i prevent 'T-Shirt' from appearing because it is ALSO inside of the category 'Ugly' which has the 'Private' set to yes?

The first instance of where i need this, my code is as follows:

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('productCategory').level(1) %}
            <li class='category{% if loop.index > 1 %} hidden{% endif %}' id='content-{{ loop.index }}'>
                <div class='description'>
                    <p>{{ category.description }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="featured-products-container">
                    {% include '_components/featured_products' %}
                    <a href='{{ category.url }}' class='full-range'>See Full Range »</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

And then the _components/featured_products template looks like this:

```
<ul class='products'>
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.relatedTo(category).order('RAND()').limit(4) %}
{% for entry in products %}
    {% set image = entry.keyImage.first() %}
    {% set prodSize = { mode: 'crop', width: 200, height: 200, position: 'center-center' } %}
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
        <img src="{{ image.url(prodSize) }}" alt="">
    </a>
    <h3 class="product-title">
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
            {{ entry.title }}
        </a>
    </h3>
{% endfor %}
```